# How to concatenate in ".erb" like haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

hello everyone i have a view _disqus.html.erb when i call that view i pass an object like this

> render "disqus", product: product ||
>   render "disqus", product: post

and i wanna concatenate something like this

> "#{product+"_path(product)""

because sometimes i send a post and sometimes i send a product and i dont wanna make other view for the posts so i just wanna concatenate the object.

code:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [
      function() {        
        $.ajax({
          method: "PATCH",
          url: '<%= product_path(product) %>',          
          data: {increment: "comment_count"}
        })
      }
    ];
};
```

> url: '<%= product_path(product) %>'

how can i concatenate ? thanks

in java would be something like this

> product+"_path(product)"

"product would be = post or = product"

i tried with this

> url: '<%= product+_path(product) %>'

but i get syntax error :(

Comment: Sometimes you want to call `product_path(product)` and sometimes `post_path(post)`?

Comment: yes my friend. how can i do that?

Comment: When do you need one and when the other one, you could use a condition instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `product_path` it's just a method. You can use metaprogramming for call method when you have a name as a string:

```
<%= send("#{product.class.name.downcase}_path", product) %>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i get this error bro undefined method `#<Post:0xa67a630>_path' for #<#<Class:0x9e21af0>:0xa679e68>

Comment: @AlienJava missed that it's objects. Edited

Comment: i think the issue happens because the string return something like this "Post_past", how can i show "post_path" or "product_path" doesn't "Post_path" or "Product_path"

Comment: it was `#<Post:0xa67a630>_path`. Because it converted object to string and result is `#<Post:0xa67a630>`

Comment: do you know other method like time_ago_in_words? but  i wanna something like this 01/02/16

Comment: you can use simple subtraction 't = Time.now - 10.days'. It was still `Time` object and you can show it in any format

Comment: no no por example i have this  =time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) and shows something like this: 12 days but i wanna show the date like this 01/04/2017 dont 12 days ago

Comment: just show the date in right format `= post.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'). Hope that understand you right